# How to get Spring-roo org.springframework.roo.annotations artifact via Nexus

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-roo, nexus

How to get Spring-roo org.springframework.roo.annotations artifact via Nexus?

We use Nexus as maven repository server.
I created new Spring Roo project, but org.springframework.roo.annotations cannot be resolved in Eclipse (STS actually) or via `mvn package`.
I have added Spring-roo repository in Nexus as http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/ and added it in public group.

I don't know if there way to force maven to download dependencies, so that I could play with different Nexus configuration. I thought the configuration above is straight forward.

I have checked http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/ remote repository via Nexus Remote "Browse Remote" and see the required jar is present there.

Comment: Have you setup a settings file in Maven? This is how you tell Maven to use a local Maven repository, instead of the default which is Maven Central

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved in Nexus by:

1. add remote repository spring-roo-repository
2. add spring spring-roo-repository as the last item to group piblic
3. waiting for some time (several hours in my case, as I don't know how make local maven check for missing artifact again)

Comment: Nexus uses Lucene for searching and perhaps your problem was that you need to force a download of the latest index. (See Nexus scheduled tasks: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-tasks.html). Attempting a build would have forced Nexus to go out and search for missing artifacts, which would have also forced a local index update.